# Is there a way to make the dbt_cloud_pr_xxxx_xxx a clone of an existing data?

Tags: continuous-integration, dbt, incremental-load

so using dbt cloud, and having a run on every pull request, but my incremental models are fully refreshed since everything runs in a new db destination (dbt_cloud_pr_xxxxx_xxx) any way of solving this? perhaps creating the new destination as a clone of an old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbt calls this "Slim CI". You can use their "deferral" and "state comparison" features -- they will check the manifest of the compiled project to the manifest from another run you specify (typically the last production run). Any models that are unchanged will have `ref()` compile to the prod target, and then you can use the `--state:modified+` selector in your dbt Cloud job definition to only rebuild the models with changes.

See the [docs for CI in dbt Cloud](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/dbt-cloud/using-dbt-cloud/cloud-enabling-continuous-integration#deferral-and-state-comparison).